# How to inherit CSS using Less?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, less-mixins

I am trying to create a legend below `<table>` where colors match those defined in Bootstrap stylesheets e.g.:

```css
.table > thead > tr > td.warning, .table > tbody > tr > td.warning, .table > tfoot > tr > td.warning, .table > thead > tr > th.warning, .table > tbody > tr > th.warning, .table > tfoot > tr > th.warning, .table > thead > tr.warning > td, .table > tbody > tr.warning > td, .table > tfoot > tr.warning > td, .table > thead > tr.warning > th, .table > tbody > tr.warning > th, .table > tfoot > tr.warning > th {
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    border-color: #fbeed5;
}
```

My approach is to define a DIV with fixed width/height and assign it a class defined in Less file where the DIV's class inherits color defined in the CSS above.

What I don't understand yet is how can I say to LESS compiler: "take properties from `.table > tbody > tr > td.warning` and insert into here"?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `&:extend(.table > thead > tr > td.warning);` inside your own class to inherit from that Element:

[View the CSS output on LESS Playground](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.table%20%3E%20thead%20%3E%20tr%20%3E%20td.warning%2C%20.table%20%3E%20tbody%20%3E%20tr%20%3E%20td.warning%2C%20.table%20%3E%20tfoot%20%3E%20tr%20%3E%20td.warning%2C%20.table%20%3E%20thead%20%3E%20tr%20%3E%20th.warning%2C%20.table%20%3E%20tbody%20%3E%20tr%20%3E%20th.warning%2C%20.table%20%3E%20tfoot%20%3E%20tr%20%3E%20th.warning%2C%20.table%20%3E%20thead%20%3E%20tr.warning%20%3E%20td%2C%20.table%20%3E%20tbody%20%3E%20tr.warning%20%3E%20td%2C%20.table%20%3E%20tfoot%20%3E%20tr.warning%20%3E%20td%2C%20.table%20%3E%20thead%20%3E%20tr.warning%20%3E%20th%2C%20.table%20%3E%20tbody%20%3E%20tr.warning%20%3E%20th%2C%20.table%20%3E%20tfoot%20%3E%20tr.warning%20%3E%20th%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20background-color%3A%20%23fcf8e3%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20border-color%3A%20%23fbeed5%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cndiv%20%7B%20%5Cn%20%20%26%3Aextend(.table%20%3E%20thead%20%3E%20tr%20%3E%20td.warning)%3B%5Cn%20%20color%3A%20blue%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D)

```
.table > thead > tr > td.warning, .table > tbody > tr > td.warning, .table > tfoot > tr > td.warning, .table > thead > tr > th.warning, .table > tbody > tr > th.warning, .table > tfoot > tr > th.warning, .table > thead > tr.warning > td, .table > tbody > tr.warning > td, .table > tfoot > tr.warning > td, .table > thead > tr.warning > th, .table > tbody > tr.warning > th, .table > tfoot > tr.warning > th {
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    border-color: #fbeed5;
}

div { 
  &:extend(.table > thead > tr > td.warning);
  color: blue;
}
```